# Anybody Integrated Zurb Foundation 3.0 with Twitter Boostrap 2.0?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I think it will be benefitting to use twitter bootstrap inside a zurb foundation layout structure.

I just havent tried it before but I think it is doable.

Implanning on using the layout structure of Foundation the will be using the thumb, dropdown, tipsy, icon buttons of Twiiter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did!

Mostly, I  integrated foundation's way cleaner grid (and some stuff like the reveal script), with Bootstrap's UI and mobile menu. A client wanted me to work with bootstrap, but I'm a foundation guy. So, this was my solution.

To keep it fairly plug and play for them, I maintained the span1 naming convention (which I hate), but replaced Bootstrap's "container" for Foundation's "row." However, this still requires the "columns" class to be added with each column. I.e.; "span4 columns."

Just soft launched the project if you want to peep it: Mogreet.com (I did everything under the root (technically: main.mogreet.com) and the Small Business link on the homepage. I did not do whats under "enterprise" or "developer" links).

Have a few items to iron out today, but you'll get the idea. If you want the files, just hit me up @sosweetcreative.